# Auto Layout Not Working in Xcode 6 debugger and crashing Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, instruments

I have come across an odd issue in Xcode 6.4. On certain screens, Auto Layout reports that my constraints are invalid, and my app throws an exception and refuses to move on. Having first encountered this issue a few days ago, I found I could use the Cocoa Layout profiler and the issue suddenly went away when I had the profiler attached. However, now I am encountering the issue again in a different place and the profiler won't start because of a stringValue issue in Cocoa Layout. When Cocoa Layout works, it crashes my Mac's Safari.

It's the same exception on both iOS sim and devices for 7.1 and 8.4.

Normally I would think this was an *actual* issue with my use of auto layout, but other members of my team do not see the same issue when running the same version on their copies, this screen's layout has worked fine for weeks (until today), and the layout works just fine on device when not attached to the debugger.

First few lines of profiler crash:

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: stringValue


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b26d0dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85f838aa -[NSLayoutConstraint description] + 678
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85d76f91 -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:] + 251
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8295149f -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_willRemoveLayoutConstraint:] + 43
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827ddfc9 -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _constraints_willChangeAutoresizingConstraintsArrayForContainedView:] + 201
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827d948e -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setAutoresizingConstraints:] + 277
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827d9277 -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _invalidateAutoresizingConstraints] + 49
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff827dc586 -[NSView _setSuperview:] + 1041
```

What Xcode tells me is wrong:

```
2015-07-23 00:52:25.622 Hinted[42128:355616] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d3ff10 V:[UILabel:0x7f8800d526a0'Jul 21, 2015'(15)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d32140 V:[UILabel:0x7f8800d32d80'Randy S.'(15)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d319c0 no_photo.width == no_photo.height   (Names: no_photo:0x7f8800d52eb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d3fa30 anonymous.width == anonymous.height   (Names: anonymous:0x7f8800d53160 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d27060 no_photo.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0.topMargin   (Names: no_photo:0x7f8800d52eb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d26f90 no_photo.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0.leadingMargin   (Names: no_photo:0x7f8800d52eb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d26ce0 V:[no_photo]-(3)-[UILabel:0x7f8800d32d80'Randy S.']   (Names: no_photo:0x7f8800d52eb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d26c40 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7f8800d32d80'Randy S.'.bottom - 9>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d17c10 H:[no_photo]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7f8800d260b0'Test reply']   (Names: no_photo:0x7f8800d52eb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d0c790 V:[anonymous]-(25)-[UILabel:0x7f8800d526a0'Jul 21, 2015']   (Names: anonymous:0x7f8800d53160 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d30120 V:[UILabel:0x7f8800d526a0'Jul 21, 2015']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d2fff0 anonymous.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0.trailingMargin   (Names: anonymous:0x7f8800d53160 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d30040 H:[UILabel:0x7f8800d260b0'Test reply']-(8)-[anonymous]   (Names: anonymous:0x7f8800d53160 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d2ff10 anonymous.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0.topMargin   (Names: anonymous:0x7f8800d53160 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f88006e6bc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8800d2cfe0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8800d32140 V:[UILabel:0x7f8800d32d80'Randy S.'(15)]>
```

Nuking Xcode's generated folders, clean build, clean build folder, reinstalling Xcode, trying Xcode 7 beta -- all no change... Same issue.

Comment: I should also add that I'm using SWTableViewCell's newest version. [SWTableViewCell's Github](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

Comment: In regards to this specific issue, [this Github issue](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/issues/233) is related, but it still doesn't explain why my colleagues do not see the same and why it works fine without a debugger attached.

Comment: Made the cell a regular UITableViewCell... somehow the view is still swipe-able and the view loads fine now.